# php mysql if not null for varchar

Tags: php, mysql

My db table is like:

```
[id] [city] [temp] [cssstyle]
[1] [London] [10] [top:15px;left:5px]
[2] [Berlin] [10] []
[3] [Paris] [10] [top:15px;left:5px]
[4] [New York] [10] []
```

cssstyle is varchar(128)

Im trying to display only rows that have cssstyle with the below command:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE cssstyle is not null")
```

but this is displaying all rows, i like to be displayed only London and Paris rows.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the row are set to `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to store empty string (`''`) rather than `NULL` in the empty fields. Those are different things in `MySQL`.

Use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    cities
WHERE   cssstyle > ''
```

By using "greater than" you give `MySQL` posibility to use an index range scan on `cssstyle`

Comment: @feeela: to filter out NULLs and empty values, using the index if possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE cssstyle IS NOT NULL OR cssstyle <> ''
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `AND` to check for both the conditions resulting into null

```
SELECT * FROM cities where cssstyle IS NOT NULL AND cssstyle <> ''
```

it will be also better if you insert `NULL` instead of `''` in your table

then your query must be enough

```
SELECT * FROM cities where cssstyle IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `LENGTH` function in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities 
WHERE LENGTH(cssstyle) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your `cssstyle` column storing default value as `null`. Better check if not empty or is null.

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE cssstyle != '' OR cssstyle IS NOT NULL
```